# Java weird behavior with left shift and plus

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Can someone explain to me why this will print out 0 instead of 2? There must be some simple (read as stupid) mistake going on here but I can't figure it out. Thanks.

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int result[] = new int[]{0,0,1,0};
        int out = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < result.length; i ++){
            out = out << 1 + result[i];
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use parentheses for bit operators (`<<`, `>>`, `>>>`, `&`, `|`, `^`).

Comment: And use `|`, not `+`, to combine  bits or bit fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `+` has higher precedence than `<<`, so you need to use parentheses to force the order of evaluation that you need:

```
out = (out << 1) + result[i];
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/IxdBhb).

Comment: Ah, that's straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: Morale: always use parenthesis (when unsure).

Comment: damn, I see no answers - and I post an answer I see two answers

Comment: @MaciejCygan Sometimes I feel like spoiled when I ask a simple question and got a lot of equally good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running this program instead (adding parenthesis):

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int result[] = new int[]{0,0,1,0};
        int out = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < result.length; i ++){
            out = (out << 1) + result[i];
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

works... - the problem seems to be with operator precedence. `+` takes precedence over `<<`

Answer (score 1):

thats why :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    int result[] = new int[]{0,0,1,0};
    int out = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < result.length; i ++){
        out = **(out << 1)** + result[i];
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

note that **  are for you to see what you have been missing